Why is my camera capabilities not showing zoom using getUserMedia()?
When I read my camera capabilities using getUserMedia() in JavaScript / HTML, the property zoom always returns null. But my Android phone has zoom functionality on the camera and other apps that use the camera.
I've read that it might appear after waiting 5 seconds, but it still return null. I am using QuaggaJS to scan barcodes.
Does anyone know why this happens?
checkCapabilities: function() {
    var track = Quagga.CameraAccess.getActiveTrack();
    var capabilities = {};
    if (typeof track.getCapabilities === 'function') {
        capabilities = track.getCapabilities();
    }

    // Apply max zoom?
    console.log('capabilities.zoom:', capabilities.zoom)

    if( capabilities.zoom )
    {
        console.log('capabilities.zoom.max:', capabilities.zoom.max)

        track.applyConstraints({ advanced: [{zoom: capabilities.zoom.max}]}).catch(e => 
        console.log(e));
    }
}

